# Is there any way to define exact amount of model time unites per second in Anylogic model run?

Tags: anylogic

Was trying to run model on monthly based calculations, but for some reason simulation runs through strange timeframes as 9.48 month, and so on. So i was wandering if there was an option to define model time units like 1 month per 10 seconds and run it.

Neither Model Properties nor Simulation Properties doesn't allow to define it

Answer (score 0):

They do allow you to define that. Set the model time unit to "Month". When you run an experiment now at "x1" speed, it will (try to) execute it at 1 month per real second. Only when your model is too computationally hard would it be slower than that.

If you want to run at 1 month per 10 second, you can always fine-tunethe speed at runtime using `getEngine().setRunSpeed(10.)` or similar to adjust the factor precisely.

Check the help, it is all documented there as well